# How to cache dynamically generated image in browser?

Tags: django, nginx, browser-cache

I generate a dynamic image on `http://example.com/image/some_param1/some_param2/`

I do:

```
HttpResponse(img.image, content_type=magic.from_file(img.image.path, mime=True))
```

It is displaying image fine, however, it is not cached in browser. I tried adding:

```
location /image {
   uwsgi_pass django;
   include /home/tomas/Desktop/natali_reality/uwsgi_params;
   expires 365d;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Maybe adding an image file extension to the dynamic request will get the browser to cache it

Comment: @RachSharp I tried that, but it just gives 404. It tries to load that file from the disk I am guessing.